# Salesforce Connection using smooks configuration

Tags: java, salesforce, smooks

How to establish **salesforce** connection using **smooks** configuration in java?

For Eg: for database connection,

```
xmlns:ds="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/datasource-1.1.xsd"
```

is used for `datasource`.

Is there something else like this for salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has loads of tools for doing this already. Why would you want to use Smooks? I ask this as the author of Smooks :)